# In Stata, how can I adjust size of coefplot's headings?

Tags: graphics, stata, coefplot

I'm working with `coefplot` command ([source](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457686.html), [docs](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457686.html)) in Stata plotting regression coefficients.

Taking the example from manual:

```
sysuse auto,clear
keep if rep78>=3

regress mpg headroom i.rep##i.foreign
coefplot, xline(0) omitted baselevels headings(3.rep78 = "{bf:Repair Record}" 0.foreign = "{bf:Car Type}" 3.rep78#0.foreign = "{bf:Interaction Effects}") drop(_cons)
```

That works as expected.

I'm now trying to tinker with the sizing of the labels of Y axis. I'd like to make them smaller to accommodate a large number of categories.

`ylab(, labs(vsmall))`

I cannot however resize the headings themselves. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `labsize(vsmall)` as a suboption within `headings()`. Example:

```
sysuse auto,clear
keep if rep78>=3

regress mpg headroom i.rep##i.foreign
coefplot, xline(0) omitted baselevels ///
    headings(3.rep78 = "{bf:Repair Record}" 0.foreign = "{bf:Car Type}" ///
    3.rep78#0.foreign = "{bf:Interaction Effects}", labsize(vsmall)) drop(_cons)
```